UnsupportedFileSystemException after spring boot starter parent version upgrade to 3.2 or 3.3
We have Spring boot application service which call Hadoop distcp API.
Application working fine with Java 17, Spring-boot-starter-parent 3.1.0 and Hadoop version 3.3.6
When we changed spring-boot-starter-parent version to 3.2 or 3.3 for OSS vulnerabilities, we get following exception:
org.apache.hadoop.fs.UnsupportedFileSystemException : fs.AbstractFileSystem.nested.impl=null : No AbstractFileSystem configured for scheme: nested
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.AbstractFileSystem.createFileSystem(AbstractFileSystem.java:177)

Need to find after upgrading which dependency causing this issue.
Is there way we can include of exclude specific dependency to overcome this issue.

It sounds like Hadoop is using your Spring Boot jar in a way that is not compatible with Spring Boot's new nested jar support. As described in the Spring Boot release notes, you can configure Maven or Gradle to use the classic nested jar support to restore the previous behavior:

For Gradle users you can set the bootJar.loaderImplementation to org.springframework.boot.loader.tools.LoaderImplementation.CLASSIC. For example:
bootJar {
 loaderImplementation = org.springframework.boot.loader.tools.LoaderImplementation.CLASSIC
}

For Maven users, you can set the <loaderImplementation> tag on the spring-boot-plugin configuration to CLASSIC. For example:
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <goals>
            <goal>repackage</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <loaderImplementation>CLASSIC</loaderImplementation>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>


